# « Tire[r] ses grègues, gagne[r] au haut » : précisions ?

Tags: sens, étymologie, expressions-idiomatiques, littérature, figure-de-style

> Sur la branche d'un arbre était en sentinelle
>  Un vieux coq adroit
>   et matois.
>  « Frère, dit un renard, adoucissant sa voix,
>  Nous
>   ne sommes plus en querelle:
>  Paix générale cette fois.
>  Je
>   viens te l'annoncer, descends, que je t'embrasse.
>  Ne me retarde
>   point, de grâce:
>  Je dois faire aujourd'hui vingt postes sans
>   manquer.
>  Les tiens et toi pouvez vaquer
>  Sans nulle crainte à
>   vos affaires;
>  Nous vous y servirons en frères.
>  Faites-en les
>   feux dès ce soir,
>  Et cependant, viens recevoir
>  Le baiser
>   d'amour fraternelle.
>   — Ami, reprit le coq, je ne pouvais jamais
>  Apprendre une plus douce et meilleure nouvelle
>  Que celle
>  De cette paix;
>  Et
>   ce m'est une double joie
>  De la tenir de toi. Je vois deux
>   lévriers,
>  Qui, je m'assure, sont courriers
>  Que pour ce sujet
>   on envoie.
>  Ils vont vite et seront dans un moment à nous
>  Je
>   descends: nous pourrons nous entre-baiser tous.
>   — Adieu, dit le renard, ma traite est longue à faire,
>  Nous nous réjouirons du succès de l'affaire
>  Une autre fois.» Le galand
>   aussitôt
>  **Tire ses grègues, gagne au haut,**
>  [image]
>  <sup>[Marc Chagall](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marc_Chagall) ds. *Les Fables de La Fontaine, 100 illustrations*, [Tériade](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C3%A9riade), Éd. *Verves*, 1952.</sup>
>  Mal content de son
>   stratagème.
>  Et notre vieux coq en soi-même
>  Se mit à rire de
>   sa peur;
>  Car c'est double plaisir de tromper le trompeur.
>
> [ [Jean de La Fontaine](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_de_La_Fontaine), *Le Coq et le Renard*, livre II, fable XV (Régnier)) ]

*Tirer ses [grègues](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/gr%C3%A8gues)* ([*grègues*](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/complement-godefroy/gr%C3%A8gues) 15<sup>e</sup>, [*tirer ses*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/gr%C3%A8gues)... 1668 : La Fontaine) et *gagner le/au [haut](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie8/haut)* (1548/DHLF), comme *[gagner](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/gagner) le/au [large](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/large)*, peuvent signifier *s'enfuir*. L'édition de *Régnier* des fables ([bnf](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k51869/f414.image), [archive.org](https://archive.org/stream/oeuvresdejdelafo01lafouoft#page/174/mode/2up)) contient quelques informations supplémentaires, dont des éléments de comparaison avec la fable d'[Ésope](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89sope).

---

- Pourquoi *La Fontaine* répète-t-il deux fois essentiellement la même
  chose, quelle est la nuance, l'effet produit, de quelle figure de style s'agit-il le cas échéant ;
  serait-ce que *tirer ses grègues* est un emploi au propre et que le
  renard portât le pantalon ; reconnaît-on encore ces vieilles expressions et que (comment) dirait-on aujourd'hui au lieu de cette juxtaposition ?
- [*Littré*](http://www.littre.org/definition/gr%C3%A8gue) disait qu'on se méprenait sur l'expression (*tirer ses*...) vu la méconnaissance du nom
  commun, avec des résultats comme *tirer ses [guêtres](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/gu%C3%AAtres)* :
  connaît-on un autre idiome/expression dont la méconnaissance d'un terme serait
  *très souvent* à l'origine d'une confusion ou d'une méprise et quelle est-elle ?
- Sur quel sens précis de *(au/le) [haut](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/haut)* s'appuie-t-on pour élaborer le sens
  de *s'enfuir* avec *gagner* (*gagner le/au haut*) ; a-t-on un exemple connu d'emploi plus ancien, au milieu du 16<sup>e</sup> (origine 1548) ?

Comment: Pas de problème de droits de reproduction avec l'image ?

Comment: @Laure À mon avis, l'utilisation en est raisonnable, non-commer., la reproduction de l’œuvre exacte de petit format ne permet pas de tirage utile, c'est la représentation d'une fable connue avec valeur didactique. Il n'y aurait aucun impact sur la valeur de l’œuvre pour les collectionneurs, le dernier de mes soucis par ailleurs, et je considère que l’œuvre du Maître doit être vue par le public. Enfin le titulaire des droits est libre de se manifester au besoin pour en exiger le retrait. La contribution CC by-sa peut incorporer l'utilisation raisonnable ou sinon  l'exclue, et n'est inquiétée...

Comment: J'emploie souvent des images et l'utilisation que j'en fais, et qui se veut des plus respectueuse à mon avis (taille minime, référence à l'auteur, lien vers l'éditeur), repose sur un jugement de bonne foi basé sur des critères objectifs dans un contexte de mise en valeur patrimoniale (et non de mise en valeur de mes questions). Et j'espère que les ayants droit comprendront cette valeur. Merci !

Comment: @Laure J'ajouterais, pour plus de certitude, que mon deuxième commentaire ne sous-entend pas que vous ne comprenez pas cela. Bien au contraire. Et votre question est pertinente. Merci !

Answer (score 2):

En une première version de ma réponse, j’y étais allé au senti, invoquant le redoublement de l’indication de fuite comme un renforcement de la presse à fuir du renard, qui opte pour deux solutions de fuite, peut-être pour l’accélérer. Les expressions choisies étaient aussi pour moi comme une image couvrant toute la verticale, le renard gagnant au haut en tirant ses grègues (lesquelles sont clairement en bas).

Une réflexion de plus longue haleine et le ressassement de la fable m’ont cependant fait apparaître de nombreux motifs de redoublement dans la fable, ce qui m’a laissé penser qu’il pouvait y avoir bien davantage que ce que suggéraient les premières impressions :

- Il y a tout d’abord l’utilisation directe du mot *« double »* en deux (justement) endroits : *« Et ce m’est une double joie », « Car c’est double plaisir de tromper le trompeur »*, ainsi que l’évocation des deux lévriers qui surviennent.
- La fuite n’est pas le seul exemple de déclaration double d’une seule et même chose : sont aussi au menu la ruse *(« Un vieux coq adroit et matois »)*, l’arrivée de la paix *(« Nous ne sommes plus en querelle : / Paix générale cette fois. »)*, l’invitation à l’embrassade *(« descends, que je t’embrasse »* et plus loin *« viens recevoir / Le baiser d’amour fraternelle »)* et la qualification de la bonne nouvelle *(« Apprendre une plus douce et meilleure nouvelle »)*.
- Et finalement le redoublement de la tromperie qui clôt la fable *(« Car c’est double plaisir de tromper le trompeur »)*.

Pourquoi donc tout dédoubler ici ? Puisque nous sommes, en apparence du moins, dans une fable sur l’amitié, la paix, la fraternité et l’amour, et que ce genre de relation implique (au moins) deux individus, je me suis dit que peut-être La Fontaine désirais contraster les associations d’éléments semblables, naturelles et constructives, à celle, hypothétique et contre-nature, d’un renard et d’un coq, êtres si dissemblables que toute collaboration entre eux ne saurait qu'être destructive.

Par simple plaisir, je prends le temps de mentionner une autre expression qui indique un état de sauve-qui-peut qui, paradoxalement, prend bien le temps de s’étendre pour mieux signifier l’empressement : *« Ne faire ni une, ni deux »*. N’y a-t-il pas là un similaire et paradoxal sentiment de redondance et de lenteur dans la description d’actions rapides guidées davantage par l’instinct que par la réflexion ?

---

**Une autre expression où la compréhension de l’un des termes s’efface avec le temps et modifie éventuellement l’usage ou la forme de l’expression ?**

Il y a *« faire long feu »*, dont les deux derniers mots sont à évaluer comme une seule expression indiquant l’échec du tir d’une arme à feu, et qui signifie au figuré manquer son coup. Une expression miroir a éventuellement émergée – *« ne pas faire long feu »* – qui semblait, mieux que l’originale, correspondre à l’idée de l’échec prématuré d’un projet, car démarrer et surtout entretenir un feu constitue pour la plupart des gens un but autrement plus commun que d’utiliser des armes à feu, d’autant plus que l’industrie a éventuellement rendu inutile l’usage du feu dans les armes à feu. Un feu trop court, non trop long, est alors un échec.

---

**Les animaux de Lafontaine étaient-ils habillés?**

Une des hypothèses proposées dans la question originale était que le renard eut porté des pantalons, et que l’expression ait été utilisée au sens propre. J’ai quelques raisons de penser que le renard allait portant fourrure et c’est tout, à partir de circonstances présentées par d’autres fables du sieur La Fontaine.

> **Le Corbeau et le Renard**
>
> Maître Corbeau, sur un arbre perché,
>   Tenait en son bec un fromage.
>   Maître Renard, par l’odeur alléché,
>   Lui tint à peu près ce langage :
>   Et bonjour, Monsieur du Corbeau,
>   Que vous êtes joli! que vous me semblez beau!
>   Sans mentir, si votre ramage
>   **Se rapporte à votre plumage**,
>   Vous êtes le Phénix des hôtes de ces bois.
>   À ces mots le Corbeau ne se sent pas de joie,
>   Et pour montrer sa belle voix,
>   Il ouvre un large bec, laisse tomber sa proie.
>   Le Renard s’en saisit, et dit : Mon bon Monsieur,
>   Apprenez que tout flatteur
>   Vit aux dépens de celui qui l’écoute.
>   Cette leçon vaut bien un fromage sans doute.
>   Le Corbeau honteux et confus
>   Jura, mais un peu tard, qu’on ne l’y prendrait plus.

Le plumage dont on loue tant la beauté est sans contredit la robe toute entière du corbeau, cette perfection de noir lissé qui ne saurait souffrir l’ajout d’une fraise, d’une cote de maille ou d’une perruque sans faire tomber la remarque du renard dans la caricature la plus grotesque.

On pourrait cependant arguer qu’un renard n’est pas un oiseau, et que l’habillement qui empêcherait ces derniers de voler (dans les airs) n’empêcherait guère le renard de voler (du fromage).

On trouvera cependant que d’autres que la gent ailée vont nus dans les fables:

> **La Grenouille qui se veut faire aussi grosse que le Bœuf**
>
> Une Grenouille vit un Bœuf
>   Qui lui sembla de belle taille.
>   Elle qui n’était pas grosse en tout comme un œuf,
>   Envieuse s’étend, et s’enfle, et se travaille
>   Pour égaler l’animal en grosseur,
>   Disant : Regardez bien, ma sœur ;
>   Est-ce assez ? dites-moi ; n’y suis-je point encore ?
>   Nenni. M’y voici donc ? Point du tout. M’y voilà ?
>   Vous n’en approchez point. La chétive Pécore
>   **S’enfla si bien qu’elle creva.**
>   Le monde est plein de gens qui ne sont pas plus sages :
>   Tout bourgeois veut bâtir comme les grands seigneurs,
>   Tout petit prince a des ambassadeurs,
>   Tout marquis veut avoir des pages.

On peut supposer à peu de risques que La Fontaine n’a pas imaginé sa grenouille comme une sorte d’incroyable Hulk déchirant les vêtements qu’elle porte avant d’atteindre, bien plus tard, une taille si disproportionnée 
à sa nature qu’elle éclate. Le lien inverse, que le très vert et très gonflant Hulk ait été en partie inspiré de cette grenouille, pour suspect qu’il puisse être, aurait au moins l’avantage de respecter la chronologie.

Des objets apparaissent bien parfois dans les fables, des colliers pour les chiens *(Le Loup et le Chien)*, des paniers ou autres types de contenants que transportent des ânes ou mulets *(L’Âne chargé d’éponges et l’Âne chargé de sel, Les deux Mulets)*. Parfois, les animaux possèdent des objets lorsque les besoins de la démonstration l’exigent, comme ici:

> **Le Renard et la Cigogne**
>
> Compère le Renard se mit un jour en frais,
>   Et retint à dîner commère la Cigogne.
>   Le régal fut petit et sans beaucoup d’apprêts :
>   Le Galand, pour toute besogne
>   Avait un brouet clair (il vivait chichement).
>   Ce brouet fut par lui servi **sur une assiette**.
>   La Cigogne au long bec n’en put attraper miette ;
>   Et le Drôle eut lapé le tout en un moment.
>   Pour se venger de cette tromperie,
>   À quelque temps de là, la Cigogne le prie.
>   “Volontiers, lui dit-il, car avec mes amis
>   Je ne fais point cérémonie.”
>   À l’heure dite, il courut au logis
>   De la Cigogne son hôtesse ;
>   Loua très fort sa politesse,
>   Trouva le dîner cuit à point.
>   Bon appétit surtout ; Renards n’en manquent point.
>   Il se réjouissait à l’odeur de la viande
>   Mise en menus morceaux, et qu’il croyait friande.
>   On servit, pour l’embarrasser
>   **En un vase à long col**, et d’étroite embouchure.
>   Le bec de la Cigogne y pouvait bien passer,
>   Mais le museau du Sire était d’autre mesure.
>   Il lui fallut à jeun retourner au logis,
>   Honteux comme un Renard qu’une Poule aurait pris,
>   Serrant la queue, et portant bas l’oreille.
>   Trompeurs, c’est pour vous que j’écris,
>   Attendez-vous à la pareille.

En nul lieu cependant je n’ai trouvé d’exemple d’un objet ou vêtement qui soit superflu, dont la présence ne soit essentielle au dénouement de l’anecdote et à l’illustration de la morale visée.

Par ailleurs, les animaux semblent aussi embarrassés que l’on pourrait les supposer lorsque vient pour eux le temps de manipuler des objets ou d’accomplir une tâche qui ne convienne pas à leur anatomie. Ainsi, le loup qui a un os pris au travers de la gorge n’est pas aidé par ses compagnons de bonne chère, loups eux aussi, mais par une cigogne, dont le bec constitue un outil approprié à la tâche. Lors du *Conseil tenu par les Rats*, il est supposé que Rodilardus, le terrifiant chat, ne saura pas enlever lui-même le grelot que l’on attacherait à son cou (il n’est pas non plus mentionné comment les rats s’y fussent pris pour l’installer, et ça demeurera pour toujours un mystère, aucun rat ne s’étant finalement porté volontaire pour cette tâche).

> **Le Loup et la Cigogne**
>
> Les Loups mangent gloutonnement.
>   Un Loup donc étant de frairie,
>   Se pressa, dit-on, tellement
>   Qu’il en pensa perdre la vie.
>   Un os lui demeura bien avant au gosier.
>   De bonheur pour ce Loup, qui ne pouvait crier,
>   Près de là passe une Cigogne.
>   Il lui fait signe, elle accourt.
>   Voilà l’Opératrice aussitôt en besogne.
>   Elle retira l’os ; puis, pour un si bon tour,
>   Elle demanda son salaire.
>   Votre salaire? dit le Loup,
>   Vous riez, ma bonne commère.
>   Quoi ! Ce n’est pas encor beaucoup
>   D’avoir de mon gosier retiré votre cou !
>   Allez, vous êtes une ingrate ;
>   Ne tombez jamais sous ma patte.

–

> **Conseil tenu par les Rats**
>
> Un Chat, nommé Rodilardus,
>   Faisait de Rats telle déconfiture
>   Que l’on n’en voyait presque plus,
>   Tant il en avait mis dedans la sépulture.
>   Le peu qu’il en restait, n’osant quitter son trou,
>   Ne trouvait à manger que le quart de son soûl ;
>   Et Rodilard passait, chez la gent misérable,
>   Non pour un Chat, mais pour un Diable.
>   Or, un jour qu’au haut et au loin
>   Le Galand alla chercher femme,
>   Pendant tout le sabbat qu’il fit avec sa dame,
>   Le demeurant des Rats tint chapitre en un coin
>   Sur la nécessité présente.
>   Dès l’abord, leur Doyen, personne fort prudente,
>   Opina qu’il fallait, et plus tôt que plus tard,
>   Attacher un grelot au cou de Rodilard ;
>   Qu’ainsi, quand il irait en guerre,
>   De sa marche avertis ils s’enfuiraient sous terre ;
>   Qu’il n’y savait que ce moyen.
>   Chacun fut de l’avis de Monsieur le Doyen ;
>   Chose ne leur parut à tous plus salutaire.
>   La difficulté fut d’attacher le grelot.
>   L’un dit : Je n’y vas point, je ne suis pas si sot ;
>   L’autre : Je ne saurais. Si bien que sans rien faire
>   On se quitta. J’ai maints chapitres vus,
>   Qui pour néant se sont ainsi tenus :
>   Chapitres, non de Rats, mais chapitres de moines,
>   Voire chapitres de chanoines.
>
> Ne faut-il que délibérer,
>   La cour en conseillers foisonne ;
>   Est-il besoin d’exécuter,
>   L’on ne rencontre plus personne.

Si un grelot faisant office de klaxon empêche un chat de chasser les souris, si un collier suffit à retenir un chien *(Le Loup et le Chien)*, si un renard ne peut utiliser une corde pour atteindre des raisins *(Le Renard et les raisins)*, une conclusion s’impose: les animaux seraient très embarrassés de mettre et d’enlever des vêtements et il est fort probable que le Renard qui voulait duper le coq ne portait pas de pantalons.

En souhaitant que l’ennui provoqué par mes digressions ait été largement compensé par le plaisir de lire ou relire l'immortel La Fontaine.

Comment: Merci ! Mais il est possible que la grenouille portât une petit veston sans manches qu'elle n'avait pas attaché, avec un petit pantalon ou bermuda,  et que seulement le ventre gonflait indépendamment ; ou le spandex ;) C'est amusant et on penche vers le vêtement naturel de l'animal, en effet !

Answer (score 1):

- Les deux expressions *tirer ses grègues* (*s'enfuir*) et *gagner au haut* (*s'éloigner*) sont maintenant inconnues, et requièrent une note explicative pour le lecteur moderne. Pour ce qui est des raisons de cette répétition, n'oublions pas la nécessité de produire un vers de la bonne longueur et de maintenir la rime. Pour ce qui est de l'effet produit, pour ma part, j'ai l'impression d'un renforcement de l'idée de fuite rapide, La Fontaine accentuerait l'empressement du renard - c'était ma première impression, et je viens juste de lire que Feelew ressent la même chose.
- Il y en a sans doute beaucoup, mais aucune qui ne me vient à l'esprit. Cette recherche [google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=expression%20mal%20utilis%C3%A9e&*) pointe plusieurs expressions qu'on utilise mal (pas tout à fait ce que vous recherchez, mais proche, et très intéressant néanmoins).
- Pour *gagner au haut* (aussi *gagner le haut*), je pense qu'on fait référence à une colline au loin, ou simplement au fait que l'horizon paraît élevé en général. Je lis cette expression un peu comme *au loin*. Mais le [dictionnaire de l'Académie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie8/haut), 8e édition, donne aussi (dans le troisième paragraphe, où l'on trouve *gagner le haut*) *Ce qui est excessif dans son genre* (l'expression *gagner le haut* elle-même est simplement définie comme *s'enfuir*). Ceci pourrait signifier que l'empressement du renard est excessif, ce qui collerait assez bien avec la fable.